# How to leave only the filenames beginning with some phrase?

Tags: string-manipulation, files-and-directories

Consider some directory `testfolder` located in the directory with the notebook. It contains the following files .dat:

```
files = FileNames["*.dat", FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "testfolder"}]];
```

Let us assume that these files are "acceptance_1.dat", "acceptance_no.dat", "spectrum_x.dat", "spectrum_12243.dat", such that `files` are

```
{"acceptance_1.dat", "acceptance_no.dat", "spectrum_x.dat", "spectrum_12243.dat"}
```

Could you please tell me which command may leave only the files beginning with `acceptance_`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
files = FileNames["acceptance_*.dat", FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "testfolder"}]];
```

Or do the filtering afterwards like:

```
files //= Select[StringStartsQ["acceptance_"]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to filter out the names inside Mathematica

```
names = FileNames["*.dat", FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "testfolder"}]];
```

If say

```
names = {"acceptance_1.dat", "acceptance_no.dat", "spectrum_x.dat", "spectrum_12243.dat"}
```

Then do

```
Flatten@StringCases[names, StartOfString ~~ "acceptance_" ~~ __]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also add `IgnoreCase -> True` for Linux systems.

```
Flatten@StringCases[names, StartOfString ~~ "acceptance_" ~~ __,  IgnoreCase -> True]
```

Comment: I would say: ```files //= Select[StringStartsQ["acceptance_"]]``` is much more readable and succinct…